# In Oracle how can "select * from my_table;" return errror ora-00904?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11gR2 (v11.2.0.4.0)

I have a simple table;

`CREATE TABLE "CLAIMS_PATIENT" 
   (    "CLAIMS_PATIENT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME_LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
    "NAME_FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "NAME_MIDDLENAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "ADDR_LINE" VARCHAR2(55 BYTE), 
    "ADDR_CITY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "ADDR_STATE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "ADDR_ZIP" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "DOB" DATE, 
    "SSN" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE), 
    "MATCH_PID" NUMBER, 
    "MATCH_SCORE" NUMBER DEFAULT -1, 
    "MATCH_DATE" DATE, 
    "PACS_STATUS" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT "CLAIMS_PATIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CLAIMS_PATIENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYDATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CLAIMS" ;`

Which I have populated with some data. using a stored procedure. Now when I attempt to do any select on the table;

```
select * from claims_patient;
select count(*) from claims_patient;
select ssn from claims_patient;
```

It returns an ora-00904 error at the last character before the semi-colon. I created this table empty on my test db, using the ddl from live db, where everything works swimmingly. I have tried using both sqldeveloper and sqlplus.

At this point I suspect something crashed and corrupted the table in my test environment, but I have never seen a corrupt table in Oracle, and I have been working with it since 1995.

Before I wipe the table and start again, what should I do to uncover the underlying cause of this problem? At this point I am curious, in case I ever see it in production, it might be useful to know what the issue is.

As requested, the results of;

`select table_name, dump(table_name) from user_tables where table_name like 'CLAIM%ENT';
is;
Typ=1 Len=14: 67,76,65,73,77,83,95,80,65,84,73,69,78,84`

Comment: Are you sure it was created in your test database with the quoted `"CLAIMS_PATIENT"`? Does the table exist in `user_tables`, and if so with what case?

Comment: Basically what I pasted was the DDL created by sqldeveloper from the table in the test DB. So I believe that I have the case, etc. correct. I tried select * from "claims_patient"; and get the the ora-00904.

Comment: It ought to give an ORA-00942 if the name/case is just wrong of course. Can you do `select table_name, dump(table_name) from user_tables where table_name like 'CLAIM%ENT'`, and add the result to the question? I can only think that one of the characters - maybe the underscore - isn't quite what it seems, either in the DDL or your query. Possibly the DDL was 'modified' by something trying to be helpful...

Comment: Added the results to the question. It seems to look good.

Comment: Yes, it isn't that then. I'd wonder about a column name but `*` and `ssn` ought to be fine too. Something does seem to be out of whack. You could poke around the data dictionary - maybe check the columns, get the DDL back out for comparison, check for invalid objects, see if there's anything in the alert log at the same time. Could be time to raise a service request though...

Comment: Actually the DDL posted above is the ddl back out from sqldeveloper.

Comment: One shot would be to remove the double quotes around the column names as those do not seem to be needed. Not so optimistic about that, but they are affecting column naming.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I did find the answer. 'Twas in an unlikely place. One of the indices, which I did not include the DDL for, was a function based index. The function became inaccessible (grant revoked) over night.

So if anyone ever finds this thread and has a table with a function based index, where the function (after the table and indices are built) becomes inaccessible, dropped, execute permissions changed, or whatever, you may get an ora-00904 when trying to access any data in the table.

It sure would be nice if Oracle were to define a more specific error that would point you in the general direction of an answer.